# How to extract value from middle of substring in SQL?

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I have column called "CustomerId" with value "1_Nissan_028" and "2_Ferrari_035".

I would like to extract "Nissan" or "Ferrari" as "CustomerName".
CustomerName is located in middle of CustomerId and lenght varies.

Following SQL query return values like "Nissan_" or "Ferrar".

How to write SQL statement?

```
SELECT cast(
        SUBSTRING(
        CustomerId,
        6,
        charindex('_', CustomerId)
        ) as nvarchar(32)
    ) as CustomerName
  
FROM [sales].[CustomerSales]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming* that the value is always the 2nd delimited value, you can use `STRING_SPLIT` and its `ordinal` column to achieve this:

```sql
SELECT SS.value AS CustomerName
FROM sales.CustomerSales CS
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(CS.CustomerId,'_',1) SS
WHERE SS.ordinal = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative quirky way of doing this would be to use *translate*

```
with customersales as (
  select '1_Nissan_028' CustomerId union select '2_Ferrari_035'
)
select customerId,
  Replace(Translate(customerId, '0123456789','__________'),'_','') CustomerName
from customersales;
```

Comment: Lil bit quirky but would also run into trouble with cars like Aston Martin DB7, VW ID.3, Tesla Model 3 etc  `PARSENAME` is cute for this, assuming strings are as simple as the example.

Comment: @wBob Yes haha in that case with a customer named DB7 you would :)